# How we can check internet connection strength of device using PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am Integrating payumoney payment gateway in client website. Sometimes success URL  is not been called due to internet connection issue. So I want to check internet connection strength and depend on it proceed to payment.  I Can't get output Please help Me...

Answer (score 1):

you can use below function and send an IP ( for example google DNS ips : 8.8.8.8 or 4.2.2.4 ... ) to check internet connection from your server

```html
    protected function ping($ip)
    {
        $output = shell_exec('ping -c1 '.  $ip);
        
        if (strpos($output, '1 received, 0% packet loss')) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

it will return 1 ( if you have internet connection ) or 0 ( if you dont )

Comment: Thanks for an answer  But I want to check signal strength not internet connected or not

Comment: hmm. you can change the shell_exec function i think you need to check time of response for example ping result : (64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=114 ms) and 'time' will show strength of connection . am i wrong ?